# Example of a pair $(X,A)$ that is not a good pair

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having trouble coming up with an example of a space $X$ (e.g. a CW structure or a $\Delta$-complex) and a pair $(X,A)$ that is NOT a good pair. I tried considering segments of edges and $2$-simplices but I'm not seeing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is CW and $A\subseteq X$ is a subcomplex, then $(X,A)$ is a good pair. I'm not sure what example you are thinking about, but it sounds like something like this, and thus is invalid.

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $A$ be the Cantor set. Then $A$ is compact, but it is not locally connected. Therefore it cannot be a retract of any open neighbourhood, since all open subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ are locally connected and retractions (like any quotient map) preserve local connectedness.